# printf и \0 окончание строки

Tags: c++, c, printf

Суть программы в том что клиент отправляет путь до папки, сервер её принимает и по аналогии утилиты DIR находит папки внутри неё и отправляет их клиенту, клиент уже выводит эти папки. Так вот проблема в том что когда сервер их нашел он отправляет их клиенту скажем так пачкой.
Например:

> Windows
>
> System
>
> Config

А когда я их вывожу через printf, выводится только `Windows`. Проблема эта в том что printf выводит пока не встретится `\0` и получается моя эта пачка выглядит так:

> Windows\0
>
> System\0
>
> Config\0

Сами программы передачи:

```
while (1)
{
    // Получаем очередную команду через канал Pipe
    if (ReadFile(hNamedPipe, szBuf, 512, &cbRead, NULL))
    {
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *entry;

        dir = opendir(szBuf);

        if (!dir) {
            perror("diropen");
            exit(1);
        };

        while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
            if (!WriteFile(hNamedPipe, entry->d_name, strlen(entry->d_name) + 1,
                &cbWritten, NULL));
        };
      if (!WriteFile(hNamedPipe, "|" , strlen(szBuf) + 1, &cbWritten, NULL));
        closedir(dir);
```

Приема:

```
// Передаем введенную строку серверному процессу
    // в качестве команды
    if (!WriteFile(hNamedPipe, szBuf, strlen(szBuf) + 1,
        &cbWritten, NULL))
        break;

    // Получаем папку от сервера
    do
    {
        if (ReadFile(hNamedPipe, szBuf, 512, &cbRead, NULL))
            printf("Received back: <%s>\n", szBuf);
    // Если произошла ошибка, выводим ее код 
    // завершаем работу приложения
    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "ReadFile: Error %ld\n",
            GetLastError());
        _getch();
        break;
    }
    } while (szBuf != "|");
```

Вот хочу узнать как правильно тогда считывать данные? Если убрать добавление \0, то есть убрать +1 то он выводит всё правильно но все одной строкой: WindowsSystemConfig и т.д.

Comment: А кто мешает просто сканировать строку дальше? Ну нуль, ну и что? Берем и идем дальше. Сколько ВСЕГО байт - мы знаем, уот и идем, пока до конца не доберемся...

Comment: @Harry у меня получается так что эти папки, которые передались в пачке, будут выведены слитно и как одна строка. Как сделать чтобы было как надо? Мне сказали что модно через memset сделать. Но я понятия не имеб как это сделать.

Comment: Вывели первую. Стали на ее конец. Это еще не конец всего? Нет? Значит, начинаем с нового символа и выводим следующую. И так, пока не будет выведено все. Или, например, по окончании добавьте еще один лишний нулевой символ, т.е. пустая строка в конце является признаком окончания.

Comment: @Harry а если не затруднит можно кодом пример? Не догоняю как реализовать просто.

Comment: Выложил ответом - в комментарии форматирования нет...

Comment: @Harry: Ну, а когда _конец_ сканирования? :-) Вы даже за последней строкой найдёте ненулевой байт.

Comment: @VladD  Мой вариант предусматривает последней - пустую строку (два нуля подряд). Это и есть ограничитель. Я же написал в ответе - последним добавьте еще один нулевой символ...

Comment: @Harry: Это если у ТС есть такая возможность :-\ Он знает длину переданного текста? (Кстати, если известна именно длина, можно итерировать до неё.)

Comment: @Harry спасибо большое, разобрался. А вот ещё небольшой вопрос, получается я считывание реализовал до тех пор пока не придёт символ "|" он у меня приходит, но происходит зацикливание, не знаете почему?

Comment: Потому что как минимум `szBuf` никогда не будет равен `"|"`. `"|"` - это строка со своим адресом, `szBuf` - другой адрес, буфера. И с чего они должны совпасть? Равенство содержимого строк проверяется с помощью функций типа `strcmp`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) возвращает количество выведенных символов без учета завершающего нуля. Это можно использовать для определения окончаний строк:

```
if(ReadFile(hNamedPipe, szBuf, 512, &cbRead, NULL))
{
         auto format_string = "Received back: <%s>\n";
   const auto format_len    = strlen(format_string) - 2;
   int c = printf(format_sting, szBuf);
   if(0 <= c)
   {
       c -= format_len;
       for(int i = c + 1; i < cbRead; i += c + 1)
       {
           c = printf(format_sting, szBuf + i);
           if(0 > c)
           {
               // ошибка
           }
           c -= format_len;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `Received back: ` - это ты тоже посчитал же.

Comment: @Qwertiy Опердил :)

Comment: У меня проще выглядит :) И нет лишних подсчётов длин.

Comment: @Cerbo спасибо большое, разобрался. А вот ещё небольшой вопрос, получается я считывание реализовал до тех пор пока не придёт символ "|"  он у меня приходит, но происходит зацикливание, не знаете  почему?

Comment: @Anrey Если вы про это `while(szBuf != "|")`, так это не мудрено ведь вы здесь сравниваете указатели а не строки. Они никогда не будут равны. Вот так надо: `while(0 != strcmp(szBuf, "|"))`, ну или так `while(*szBuf != '|')`

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте при отправке по окончании лишний нолик - чтоб структура была как тут... (Тут даже 2 лишних нолика - я просто сделал, чтоб понятнее было). Так проще всего:

```
char * output= "Windows\0Program Files\0Users\0Prochaya khren\0\0";

void print(const char * out)
{
    for(const char * c = out; *c; c += strlen(c)+1)
        printf("<%s>\n",c);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    print(output);
}
```

Comment: Можно обойтись без `strlen`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Можно. Либо сканировать, либо считать, что `printf` выводит. Но если он выводит что-то сложное, то это трудно, а `%n` использовать категорически не рекомендуется. А если там не `printf`, а какая-то другая обработка? Или что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Можете предоставить пример, когда `%n` приводит к ошибкам? (кроме *мнения M$ экспертов по безопасности*)

Comment: Да не помню я точно. Где читал - у Сикорда, "Безопасное программирование на C и C++". Если очень важно - напомните завтра :), сейчас уже комп выключаю - тогда поищу книгу и что там писали...

Comment: Вообще, мне не слишком важно. А пишут, например, в man по printf пишут очевидную вещь -- `Code such as printf(foo); often indicates a bug, since foo may  contain
       a  % character.  If foo comes from untrusted user input, it may contain
       %n, causing the printf() call to write to memory and creating  a  secuity hole.`, но речь все-таки не о явном формате, а об untrusted user *foo*

Answer (score 2):

http://ideone.com/pKA3Zp
http://ideone.com/ffjDAv

```
#include <cstdio>

char *names = "Windows\0System\0Config\0";

int main() {
  int l, r;

  for (char *name=names; *name; name+=r-l+1)
    if (printf("Folder: %n%s%n\n", &l, name, &(r=0)), !r)
      break; // Произошла ошибка, вероятно, стоит что-то сделать

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А `l` и `r` не инициализированые, чему вы молодеж учите.

Comment: `%n` - готовая дыра для взлома, вообще говоря...

Comment: @Cerbo, они printf'ом инициализируются же.

Comment: @Harry, покажешь, как взломать этот код?

Comment: @Qwertiy Каким именно компилятором собранный? :) Словом, читайте Р. Сикорд *Безопасное программирование на C и C++* - там подробно расписано, как. А в MSDN пишут вот что: **Поскольку формат %n является небезопасным, по умолчанию он запрещен.  Если в строке формата имеется символ %n, вызывается обработчик недопустимого параметра, как описано в разделе Проверка параметров.  Чтобы включить поддержку %n, изучите раздел _set_printf_count_output.**

Comment: @Harry, если код кривой, то есть куча опасных мест. Чем конкретно данному коду может навредить `%n`, из того, что не могло бы произойти, если его не использовать? Вот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509811/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Да вообще полагаться на конкретную функцию... Завтра ему надо будет не выводить через printf, а передавать куда-то - что, оставлять printf только для того, чтоб разделить строку на кусочки?...

Comment: @Harry, тогда стоит сделать функцию, которая превращает это в `vector<string>`, но ведь вопрос именно о выводе.