# Чем плох %n в printf?

Tags: c++, c, безопасность, инспекция-кода, language-lawyer

http://ideone.com/ffjDAv

```
#include <cstdio>

char *names = "Windows\0System\0Config\0";

int main() {
  int l, r;

  for (char *name=names; *name; name+=r-l+1)
    if (printf("Folder: %n%s%n\n", &l, name, &(r=0)), !r)
      break; // Произошла ошибка, вероятно, стоит что-то сделать

  return 0;
}
```

Понятно, что при скармливании `printf`у пользовательских строк в качестве формата, `%n` может сделать что-то нехорошее. Но есть ли от него вред в подобном коде по сравнению с вариантом, в котором он не используется?

http://ideone.com/xd5SYu

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

char *names = "Windows\0System\0Config\0";

int main() {
  for (char *name=names; *name; name+=strlen(name)+1)
    printf("Folder: %s\n", name);

  return 0;
}
```

PS: На основе обсуждения в другом [ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509803/178988).

Comment: @Abyx, да, запятая. Но она уж точно не является дырой в безопасности :)

Comment: А в мозгах читателей? :-D

Comment: Покамест нашёл лишь эксплоиты, если программист написал `printf(s)`, имея в виду `printf("%s", s)`. Но такой код крешнет программу и без `%n`, с одним лишь `%s`, и является абонементом на прочистку мозгов у начальства.

Comment: @VladD, в том-то и дело) А в [соседний вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509815/178988) не заглядывал?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Заглядывал, но пока там мне нечего сказать :)

Comment: IMHO нормально. Я бы только `if` написал без проверки `r`, вот так `if ((rc = printf(...)) < 0) break;`, поскольку, как пишут в man -- `If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.`. / Я не вижу тут каких-то дыр. / А разница между 1) и 2) -- первый эффективней, работа `strlen` (почти даром?) выполняется в `printf`, но сложней для восприятия (однако, лично я за 1)).

Comment: @avp, но ведь printf возвращает число записанных байт? Если я правильно понимаю, он может вывести не всё (например, место на диске закончилось при перенаправлении вывода), не присвоить `r` и вернуть какое-то значение посреди строки. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Если printf отработал нормально, он выводит число записанных в поток байт (реальная запись на device может еще и не происходить), при ошибке возвращает отрицательное число (какое именно, не знаю, сам ни разу не проверял и не нарывался)

Answer (score 1):

Если потом вместо `printf` кто-нибудь напишет `wprintf` - то первый код сломается для строк, содержащих национальные символы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните подробнее на каких платформах\реализациях это происходит и почему.